# How to get progress of successful build through Jenkins Python API

Tags: python, rest, jenkins

I have written python code to retrieve information about build. I prints a summary of successful and unsuccessful builds.

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
t = PrettyTable(['Job name','Successful','Failed','Unstable','Aborted','Total Builds','Failure Rate'])
t1 = PrettyTable(['Status', 'Job name','Build #','Date','Duration','Node','User'])

aggregation ={}

jobs = server.get_all_jobs(folder_depth=None)
for job in jobs:
    print(job['fullname'])
    aggregation[job['fullname']] = {"success" : 0 , "failure" : 0 , "aborted" : 0, "unstable":0}
    info = server.get_job_info(job['fullname'])
    # Loop over builds
    builds = info['builds']
    for build in builds:


            information = server.get_build_info(job["fullname"], 
                                        build['number'])

            if "SUCCESS" in information['result']:

                aggregation[job['fullname']]['success']  =  str(int(aggregation[job['fullname']]['success']) + 1)

            if "FAILURE" in information['result']:

                aggregation[job['fullname']]['failure']  =  str(int(aggregation[job['fullname']]['failure']) + 1)

            if "ABORTED" in information['result']:

                aggregation[job['fullname']]['aborted']  =  str(int(aggregation[job['fullname']]['aborted']) + 1)
            if "UNSTABLE" in information['result']:

                aggregation[job['fullname']]['unstable']  =  str(int(aggregation[job['fullname']]['unstable']) + 1)

            t1.add_row([ information['result'], job['fullname'],information["id"],datetime.fromtimestamp(information['timestamp']/1000),information["duration"],"master",information["actions"][0]["causes"][0]["userName"]])

    total_build = int(aggregation[job['fullname']]['success'])+int(aggregation[job['fullname']]['failure'])
    t.add_row([job["fullname"], aggregation[job['fullname']]['success'],aggregation[job['fullname']]['failure'],aggregation[job['fullname']]['aborted'],aggregation[job['fullname']]['unstable'],total_build,(float(aggregation[job['fullname']]['failure'])/total_build)*100])

with open('result', 'w') as w:
    w.write(str(t1))
    w.write(str(t))
```

This is what the output looks like:
[image]

And this is what Windows batch execute command looks like:

```
cd E:\airflowtmp
conda activate web_scraping
python hello.py
```

hello.py prints hello world. If I add print counter =100 or something like this then how do I return it and print it in this resultant table.

Edit:

I am trying to get some kind of variable from code to display. For instance if Im scraping pages and scraper ran successfully then I want to know the number of pages that it scraped. You can think of it as a simple counter. Is there any way to return a variable from Jenkins to python

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. How is your hello world script connected to the one about getting build information?

Comment: @Ardweaden I have edited the question. Please let me know in case of obscurity

Comment: Jenkins itself does not know anything about the nature of your jobs, e.g. how many pages were scrapped, or anything to that matter. Your job should store this information somewhere and your script can read that information from the storage. You may want to check consul, redis, or influx as alternatives.